# Why won't my Xbox 360 boot

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

My Xbox 360 won't boot I turn it on and the green light come on the Xbox but nothing shows up on the screen I have tried everything to fix it. I unplugged it all and reconnected it and unplugged the HDMI cord and tried reconnecting that to see if the was the problem but it wasn't and the Xbox is very sensitive and if you touch the Xbox it automatically turns on I don't know if that is supposed to happen but it does. When I turn the controller on the x flashes but it doesn't turn on it just keeps flashing. It think it might have overheated or something cause I woke up and it was on so what do I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you ever (or at least remember) turning your Xbox sideways while playing a game or drop it on a hard surface? Those could severely damage your Xbox's internals. If that isn't the case, try changing the HDMI cords and/or your TV. Oh yeah, one that gets me all of the time is to make sure your source (it usually is a button on your remote) is on HDMI (sometimes, there is multiple, and check each one).

Comment: For your controller, try/buy another one. If that doesn't work, maybe you've damaged your Bluetooth signal in your Xbox. If none of this works, see if you can send your Xbox to a shop (or Microsoft's repair factory thing, I don't know the exact name) to get it fixed. If even that doesn't work, you might have to get a new one. But hey, gives you another reason to buy next gen (or shall I say, current gen)! :-D

Comment: Is it plugged in.